# I am facing issue with masking my values for a Column in a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
WORKER_REF_ID   BONUS_AMOUNT    BONUS_DATE
      1            5000      2016-02-20 00:00:00.000
      1            4500      2016-02-20 00:00:00.000
      2            3500      2016-06-11 00:00:00.000
```

This is how my Bonus1 Table look like and I want to mask the Bonus_Amount column in the table.I am using the below code for masking the same but getting some issue executing it.

```
  alter table [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[Bonus1]
  alter column Bonus_Amount add masked with (function ='random(1,5)').
```

How to resolve the issue.This is the error message I am getting :-

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: did you tried without using `add` keyword?

Comment: @Simonare yeah but I am still getting error as "Incorrect syntax near 'function' expecting '(' or SELECT  "

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Are you using SQL-Server 2016? This is a SQL Server 2016 feature, so in earlier versions you will get this error.

Comment: @Simonare I am using 2014 version.

Comment: The strange thing is that staying on 2014 you are NOT getting **Incorrect syntax near 'masked'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Masking feature is supported by SQL Server 2016+

You cannot use masking feature with SQL Server 2014.

If you insist on using data masking, you can make your own map by creating and using views.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.testview
AS
SELECT
    CreditCardID,
    CardType,
    CONCAT( '**********', RIGHT( CardNumber, 4 ) ) AS [CARDNUMBER_MASKED],
    ....
from ...
```

[Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0daa7424-ff16-4a4e-a68c-6de33c68af67/data-masking-in-sql-server-2014?forum=sqlgetstarted)